# How to edit the result value of the search results per page in Search portlet?

Tags: search, liferay

[image]

Hi, i have added the search portlet to my portal. As you can see, the default value of number of results shown per page is 20. I want to change this size to 5. Ho do i change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default number of entries to display per page - the delta - can be configured in portal-ext.properties:

```
##
## Search Container
##

    #
    # Set the default number of entries to display per page.
    #
    search.container.page.default.delta=20
```

Other properties worth to mention:

```
    #
    # Set the available values for the number of entries to display per page. An
    # empty value, or commenting out the value, will disable delta resizing.
    #
    # Always include the value specified in the property
    # "search.container.page.default.delta", since it is the default page size
    # when no delta is specified. The absolute maximum allowed delta is 200.
    #
    search.container.page.delta.values=5,10,20,30,50,75

    #
    # Set the maximum number of pages available above and below the currently
    # displayed page.
    #
    search.container.page.iterator.max.pages=25

    #
    # Set this to false to remove the pagination controls above or below
    # results.
    #
    search.container.show.pagination.top=true
    search.container.show.pagination.bottom=true
```